# improper integral $\int_{0}^{1}\ln(e^{1/x}+1)\ dx=$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Can somebody please help me with this improper integral?
$$\int_{0}^{1}\ln(e^{1/x}+1)\ dx=$$
$$\lim_{\epsilon\to\ 0^+}\int_{0+\epsilon}^{1}\ln(e^{1/x}+1)\ dx=$$
$$\ln(1+x)\approx x \implies \ln(e^{1/x}+1)\approx e^{1/x}$$
$$\lim_{\epsilon\to\ 0^+}\int_{0+\epsilon}^{1}e^{1/x} dx=?$$
I'm stuck from there
Any suggestion would be great

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all $\;\epsilon\in\big]0,1\big[\;,\;$ it results that

$$\int_{\epsilon}^{1}\ln\left(e^{\frac{1}{x}}+1\right)\ dx>\int_{\epsilon}^{1}\ln\left(e^{\frac{1}{x}}\right)\ dx=\int_{\epsilon}^{1}\frac{1}{x}\ dx=-\ln\epsilon.$$

Since $\;\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\left(-\ln\epsilon\right)=+\infty\;,\;$ it follows that $$\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_\epsilon^1\ln\left(e^\frac{1}{x}+1\right)\ dx=+\infty\;.$$

Hence,

$$\int_0^1\ln\left(e^\frac{1}{x}+1\right)\ dx=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_\epsilon^1\ln\left(e^\frac{1}{x}+1\right)\ dx=+\infty\;.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\log(1+x)\sim x $$ is for small values of $x$.

When $x=\frac 1 {10}$, $e^{\frac 1 x}=e^{10} \sim 22026$ and the value of the integrand is  $\cdots  10.0000454$.

Could $\frac 1x$ be a better approximation ?

Write instead
$$e^{\frac{1}{x}}+1=e^{\frac{1}{x}} \left(1+e^{-\frac{1}{x}}\right)$$ Taking logarithms
$$\log\left(e^{\frac{1}{x}}+1 \right)=\frac{1}{x}+\log\left(1+e^{-\frac{1}{x}}\right)\sim \frac{1}{x}+e^{-\frac{1}{x}}$$ Sooner or later, you will learn that (one integration by parts is needed)
$$\int e^{-\frac{1}{x}}\,dx=\text{Ei}\left(-\frac{1}{x}\right)+x\,e^{-\frac{1}{x}} $$ where appears the [xponential integral function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).

So
$$\int_\epsilon^1\log\left(e^{\frac{1}{x}}+1 \right)\,dx\sim-\text{Ei}\left(-\frac{1}{\epsilon }\right)+\text{Ei}(-1)-e^{-1/\epsilon }
   \epsilon -\log (\epsilon )+\frac{1}{e}$$

$$\text{Ei}\left(-\frac{1}{\epsilon }\right)=e^{-\frac 1 \epsilon } \left(-\epsilon +\epsilon ^2+O\left(\epsilon ^3\right)\right)$$

$$\int_\epsilon^1\log\left(e^{\frac{1}{x}}+1 \right)\,dx\sim\text{Ei}(-1)-e^{-\frac 1 \epsilon} \epsilon ^2-\log (\epsilon )+\frac{1}{e}$$

Trying for $\epsilon=10^{-k}$ (using $\text{Ei}(-1)\approx -0.219384$)
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & \text{approximation} &\text{exact} \\
 1 & 2.45108 & 2.43522 \\
 2 & 4.75367 & 4.73780 \\
 3 & 7.05625 & 7.04039 \\
 4 & 9.35884 & 9.34297 \\
 5 & 11.6614 & 11.6456 \\
 6 & 13.9640 & 13.9481
\end{array}
\right)$$